# What does the word 「やり」 mean?

Tags: verbs, manga

It was said by a guy who has just realized that his kid has done something improperly.

Here is the sentence including the word.

> 丈{じょう}のやろうついにやってはならねえことまで　**やり**やがったか....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word here is やる 'do'.

連用形 + やがる is a way of demeaning the participator in an action. Much like -て + しまう, it indicates discontent with the fact that the action happened; but unlike with しまう, the discontent is directed primarily at the person who chose to do the action (rather than しまう's focus more on the typically unintended action itself). It can be rendered with phrases like 'had the gall to do', 'went and did', etc; though often it works to just leave it untranslated.

Comment: On possible way to translate it would be "he f\***ing [verb in past tense]", like 俺のツナサンド食べやがった "he f\***ing ate my tuna sandwich". (I like tuna sandwiches.)

Comment: While やがる sounds really rough in Japanese, I don't think it sounds quite as bad as "fucking"... Could you imagine DBZ characters dropping f-bombs every sentence in the English dub?

Comment: A somewhat toned-down equivalent might work (eg 'fricking'), but the sense is mildly different - English 'fricking' etc focuses on the action being unexpected (either in degree or just the fact that it happened); Japanese やがる focuses on the action being the result of a willful bad choice.